# Get Joomla Website without FTP or MYSQL with Super User

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I would like to know if it's possible to download/get a Joomla website without ftp or phpmyadmin.

I have got super user account however I am having problems with an old developer. I want to get the website and move it to a new server.

Are there extensions to do this?

Thanks

Comment: I don't get how this was off-topic for SO. I would also like to know if there is a way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Admin Acces try using Akeeba

[Akeeba Backup](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-backup.html)

You can backup your site and easily put in another server using Akeeba Kickstart

[Akeeba Kickstart](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-kickstart.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are some third-party solutions for back-up that are listed in the Joomla Extension Directory at joomla.org. You would need access to the Joomla admin to install them. But in order to move it anywhere else, you are going to need access to create a new MySQL database.

My professional recommendation is not to use this method unless you have no other choice though. In case you and others don't know, the preferred method is to create a tar ball of the website and do a mysqldump of the database. Once the files are restored along with the database, the configuration.php file that resides in the root directory of the Joomla installation needs to be edited for the new configuration.